# MongoError: can't get query executor with geoNear Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get results from DB using geoNear in Moongose but it is giving "can't get query executor" error.

```js
 
// Schema
let dealSchema = new Schema({
userId: {type: String, required: true},
images: {type: [String], required: true},
location: {
    lng: {type: Number},
    lat: {type: Number},
    name: {type: String, required: true}
},
description: {type: String, required: false, default: ""},
expiredReports: {type: [String], required: false},
inappropriateReports: {type: [String], required: false},
likes: {type: [String], required: false},
dislikes: {type: [String], required: false},
comments: {type: [commentSchema], required: false},
creationDate: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
updationDate: {type: Date, default: new Date()}
}, {collection: TableName.DEAL});


function getAll(radius) {
var point = {type: "Point", coordinates: [9, 9]};

        let distance = parseInt(radius);
        if (isNaN(distance)) {
            return callback(new Error("Invalid Radius"), null)
        }

        var geoOptions = {
            spherical: true,
            maxDistance: distance,
            num: 10
        };

        DealData.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function (err, docs, stats) {
                console.log(docs);
            }
        );
   
}
```

This is my model of Mongoose and My code to get data from Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoNear method requires 2dsphere index, after creating that index you'll be able to querying data by coords.

Example:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    location: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}
  });
```

The first item of the location field is longtitude and the second one is latitude